# Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework' error

Tags: asp.net

I have deployed my websitete using filezilla client. But i encounter the following problem.

Collapse | Copy Code
Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.

Source Error:

```
     Line 6:  <configuration>
    Line 7:     <system.web>
Line 8:      <compilation debug="true" targetframework="4.0">
Line 9:             <assemblies>
Line 10:                <add assembly="sysglobl, Version=4.0.0.0,                Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" /></assemblies></compilation>
```

Source File: C:\Inetpub\vhosts\dhuvara.com\httpdocs\sub\asp\web.config    Line: 8

I red all the error details regarding this error. everything says that change the framework to 4.0. but actually i am using framework 4.0. i dont know to how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Default framework of your webserver may be 2.0 or something.

If you have access to your IIS web server, please check the target framework of the application pool. Change the target framework of the application pool of your website to 4.xxxx.

Comment: I am deploying my website to a webserver which is i purchased from  webhost provider using filezilla client software to uploading file. here may i need  iis to be run under framework 4.o. and also my iis server running on 4.0.

Comment: Most probably default target framework of your hosting server is a different version. They may be able to change the target version for your website to 4.0. Please contact them.